# Accept command does not pause when SQL script executed from a window batch file

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

While running the following batch file, it executes the sql script and then exit. Here is the content of 
runsql.bat

```
  echo exit | sqlplus <userAuthString> @scriptWithAccept.sql
```

scriptWithAccept.sql

```
   ACCEPT Continue CHAR PROMPT 'Press <CTRL>+C to cancel or any other key to continue.'
```

The problem is that batch does not pause to accept the user input provided in the Sql script. It pauses if I run the sql file from sqlplus window. I also tried using the following

```
start sqlplus <userAuthString> @scriptWithAccept.sql
```

this opens a new window and pauses for accept but it does not exit the sqlplus command window. This can be fixed by adding the exit to the end of the sql file but I don't want the exit command inside the sql file.

Comment: "but I don't want the exit command inside the sql file." - why not?

Comment: @Littlefoot - I'm doing this exercise to test it locally. In the build process this sql file will be executed with many other sqls. I can add exit and while finalizing remove it if there is no other way

Comment: Could you switch to PL/SQL? I mean: instead of calling many SQL files, put everything into a stored procedure (or even a package) and then call those procedures by passing parameters whose values are now acquired by SQL*Plus' ACCEPT.